# Why SDRAM1 and SDRAM2 have the same pins on STM32

Tags: stm32, sdram

can someone please help me,

why do when i use SDRAM1 and then add SDRAM2 the data and address pins are the same but only the chip enalbe. does this mean that all pins even the Data pins DQ can be connected parallel for both chips? have someone a reference design that uses both SDRAM controllers in the same time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Useful search term : tri-state buses.

Answer (score 2):

The chips do not do anything if they are not enabled. Therefore, to use multiple chips on the same bus, you need multiple chip enables.

Comment: thanks for answering, i know for sdram2 there are separate chip enable. but does this mean that i can connect DQ0-8 from the first sdram and DQ0-8 from the second together then to the MCU, so if one of them is not enabled, does this effect the enabled one? should i use 2 times 22Ohm for each pin then connect them to MCU or 1 time 22Ohm take the node to SDRAMs?

Comment: I am sure how to connect them is in the manual. Have you read the manual how the chips are supposed to be connected? I mean, you did not say which STM32 of all the hundreds of models you are using, so I can't open the manual and look it up for you.

Comment: Hello, thank you again for trying to answer the question, i am using STM32F469BIT6.